# How I can solve these Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Here is my code in java :

```
try{
    String query = "INSERT INTO tb_user VALUES ('"+txt_nidn.getText()+"','"+txt_nikdosen.getText()+"','"+txt_namadosen.getText()+"','"+txt_alamat.getText()+"')";
    stat = koneksi.createStatement();
    int res = stat.executeUpdate(query);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data Berhasil Di Simpan","Informasi",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    gettabel();
    bersih();
} catch (SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proses Penyimpanan Gagal atau Cek Koneksi Anda!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Is there something wrong in my code? I can't insert some data to database, because of these erroring. Please help me :(

Comment: "Is there something wrong in my code?" - Yes, it's horribly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. The *very first thing* to fix is that. Use parameterized SQL with `PreparedStatement`. Once you've done that, it'll be *much* easier to see the details of the SQL, and the other errors will be fixed more easily. (I'd specify the columns explicitly too, personally...)

Comment: error message is very clear, ```tb_user``` doesn't have 4 columns, check your table

Answer (score 2):

Using PreparedStatement, you can prevent SQL injection attacks.

```
try{
    String query = "INSERT INTO TB_USER"
        + "(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4) VALUES"
        + "(?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, txt_nidn.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(2, txt_nikdosen.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(3, txt_namadosen.getText());
    preparedStatement.setString(4, txt_alamat.getText());
    preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Data Berhasil Di Simpan","Informasi",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    gettabel();
    bersih();
} catch (SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Proses Penyimpanan Gagal atau Cek Koneksi Anda!","Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Please don't forget to change `TB_USER` column name. Replace all `COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4` to your tables column name.

All credit goes to Jon Skeet.

Related Link:

1. http://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface
2. http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/
3. http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertRecordsUsingPreparedStatement.htm